# Proxmox - how to improve low IO performance?

Tags: vmware-esxi, proxmox

**I am extremly surprised with the low IO performance of `Proxmox 6.3.3`  , which is in the following configuration and the result Image**

- Proxmox 6.3.3
- 512 GB NVMe SSD
- Create new VM content windows server 2019 **(the IO test performed inside it)**

[image: Proxmox 6.3.3 IO Performance]

But I tried to install `VMware ESXi 6.7` in the same server to understand what is the source of the issue   and to test the IO performance, and I got the following result.

- VMware ESXi 6.7
- 512 GB NVMe SSD
- Create new VM content windows server 2019 **(the IO test performed inside it)**
  `configured with the same CPU Cors/RAM/Disk Size of the previous test`

[image: VMware ESXi 6.7 IO Performance]

**Is there any thing have to do with `Proxmox` to improve the IO performance ?**

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would improve the performance if you follow best practices of running Windows virtual machine on KVM Virtualization.

- Install VirtIO drivers.
- Configure Disk cache based on your workload.
- Install Guest Service

More info here:

- [Windows 10 guest best practices](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_10_guest_best_practices)
- [Windows VirtIO Drivers](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Windows_VirtIO_Drivers)

Comment: I'm considering to migrate a VMware setup with a couple of Windows servers to Proxmox. I moved away from virsh/kvm for issues with io performance and backups. It is interesting to see, that after about 10 years some of the pain points apparently still exist. Super curious to hear if your recommendations will make the difference, I'll receive some extra server hardware soon, will try to do a similar experiment to what has been described in this question.

Comment: @phhe Did you ever try this - did the recommendations help?